# VかV-negか vs. V | V-neg vs. Vかどうか

Tags: grammar, word-choice, embedded-question

Is there any difference in meaning between these three structures? I think they all roughly mean "whether or not" but are they interchangable? Examples below:

> 両親は**賛成するかしないか**にかかわらず、僕は君と結婚します。

vs

> 明日**来る来ない**にかかわらず、必ずわたしに電話してください。

vs

> 明日は仕事を**守れるかどうか**が不安だった。

Comment: Are you missing the `か`in the second example sentence? (`...来る*か*来ない*か*...`)  Or was the sentence intentionally composed this way?

Comment: @ajsmart  There should be no issue with this usage. Leaving the か out is acceptable. するしない is considered an viable alternative to するかしないか in dialogue.

Comment: @user27280 Of course, but I only asked because it appeared in the OP's title in the question, since it seemed that he wanted to use か in the sentence in question.

Comment: @ajsmart Sorry, I ordered the examples incorrectly. They should now match the order I used in the title. 来る来ない matches the V | V-neg in the title and is exactly as I found it in a sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the forms that you have listed have the same effective meaning and are interchangeable, so long as they follow the proper context. Cross-searching these examples on [Weblio](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84), they are pretty much all listed as synonyms, with some seemingly trivial usage differences that I do not think will actually dissuade most speakers from using them interchangeably.

> するかしないか   standard colloquial
>
> するしない     casual colloquial
>
> ---
>
> するかどうか    standard (spoken or written)
>
> するか否｛いな｝か     formal (usually written); somewhat pedantic

To use as an example some advice once given by Master Yoda:

> 「やる」か、「やらない」かだけだ　→　OK
>
> 「やる」、「やらない」だけだ　→　OK
>
> 「やる」かどうかだけだ　→　a little strange (not quite casual enough)
>
> 「やる」か否かだけだ　→　strange (mixing formal with casual)

Finally, 「するのかしないのか、」or 「するのしないの、」 could be used to carry a separate nuance; one of impatience and frustration; e.g. ‘So, are you going to do it or not!?’.

If someone has another take I will be happy to consider editing.

Comment: I believe the reading of 否 in `か否か` is 「いな」, not 「ひ」.